# Cannot Connect to Any Websites While On Work VPN

Tags: google-chrome, vpn

My work uses FortiClient for our VPN service.  I can connect to our VPN just fine, and I can access my shared drive on one of our servers.  However, when I try to launch Chrome and connect to any website I get this error.

[image]

The second I disconnect from the VPN, my Chrome pages will load again.

I have tried using my phone's hotspot as the Internet connection, and the VPN works fine while on the hotspot, including the Chrome pages loading.  So I think it is something wrong with my router.

I have Spectrum/Time Warner Cable as my ISP, and when I called them, they said there's nothing they can do because my Internet connection technically is working.

Is there any kind of setting I can check in my router to see if it is blocking my work VPN?  I have the Ubee router that was provided to me by TWC.

Answer (score 0):

I spoke with the people at FortiClient and they had me manually change the DNS that the VPN was using to be Google's 8.8.8.8 address.  Everything worked once I did that.

[image]